# Polybase create external datasource giving syntax error

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm trying to execute the following command in Azure Data Warehouse:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE Brand WITH (TYPE=HADOOP, LOCATION ='wasbs://brand@mywarehouse.blob.core.windows.net' CREDENTIAL = StorageCred);
```

And I get this error message:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'HADOOP'.
```

I've tried it with and with the command after hadoop, nothing seems to work.  Azure Data Warehouse reports version 13.0.400 and I've tried with two versions of SQL Management Studio with the most recent being version 13.0.600.65

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're not actually getting the command to Azure SQL DW. Look at what I recommended to this guy, and use SSDT instead of SSMS, and see if that resolves it for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32693813/144351

Comment: Evidently while Microsoft said they provisioned it as an Azure DW, they in fact did not.  Fortunately the preview is now fully available, unfortunately not in the region I want it in.  It was exceptionally hard to find the right people to ask, wish they had better methods of actually getting the right support people.

Comment: Randy, I am sorry to hear about your experience. In the future, you can report Azure SQL DW related issues to the azure support team using the "Help + Support" tile on the portal. Here are the instructions:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-get-started-create-support-ticket/

Comment: Unfortunately even as of today this error is still valid. 
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE AzureStorage
WITH (
    TYPE = HADOOP,
    CREDENTIAL = AzureStorageCredential,
    LOCATION = 'https://demodwstoragejp.blob.core.windows.net'
);

trying above was giving me
"Failed to execute query. Error: Incorrect syntax near 'HADOOP'."

Answer (score 1):

This can also be caused by using Serverless SQL Pool incorrectly as it does not support writing so cannot be used as a sink, it also cannot be used with the "Staging" option.