# Polybase: Can't connect to Azure Blob from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, networking, azure-virtual-machine, polybase, sql-server-2019

I am trying out the new [Polybase-Feature in SQL-Server by connecting to a CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-configure-azure-blob-storage?view=sqlallproducts-allversions). However I do not manage to connect to the Azure Blob Storage:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE AzureBlob WITH (
    TYPE = HADOOP,
    LOCATION = 'wasbs://myfolder@myblob.blob.core.windows.net',
    CREDENTIAL = mycredential
);
GO
```

I always get an error saying:

> Incorrect syntax near 'HADOOP'

My SQL Server runs on an Azure VM, however I am not sure which services are supposed to be running:
[image]

I also checked TCP/IP is enabled. 
[image]

I also tried using SSDT and dsql-files as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901234/polybase-create-external-datasource-giving-syntax-error) - but the error doesn't go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I accepted Alexander's answer, it turns out that the option `BLOB_STORAGE` doesn't allow to create external tables. The option `HADOOP` was the correct one for me. There were three steps I needed to do to make the `HADOOP` option work:

1. Re-install Java Runtime Environment
2. Repair the SQL Server Installation
3. Restart the Virtual Machine

Then the `SQL`-Statement from my question worked.

Comment: why accept it answer? Please change it and make yours the answer

Comment: 5th, have you also tried to enable this option: "'polybase enabled" ?

Answer (score 3):

> However I do not manage to connect to the Azure **Blob Storage**

Should it not be a `Type=BLOB_STORAGE`?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE AzureBlob WITH (
    TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
    LOCATION = 'wasbs://myfolder@myblob.blob.core.windows.net',
    CREDENTIAL = mycredential
);
```

**Update 2020-02-18:**

I encounter the same famous message recently:

> Incorrect syntax near 'HADOOP'

It can be fixed running:

```
exec sp_configure 'polybase enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE
```

Microsoft built a nice page: [Configure PolyBase to access external data in Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-configure-azure-blob-storage?view=sqlallproducts-allversions). However, they didn't include that important command.

I think it could also be a reason of the initial issue of 5th

Comment: Thanks it works now, for some reason I assumed Microsoft documentation is up-to-date :P

Comment: @5th, you welcome, despite that your SQL Instance run in Azure VM, it is still fully sized instance and not Azure SQL DB. Perhaps this can be misleading..

Comment: Thanks - I am aware of that. For some reason in my firm we do not have VM-Ware, I guess they will act when I use AzureVMs often enough.

Comment: @Blue Clouds, this is correct, PolyBase is not part of Azure SQL DB